# VMC cannot detect application type when publishing Play Framework 2.0 app to CloudFoundry

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy zentasks sample of playframework 2.0 to cloudfoundry.com following the Play Framework [tutorial](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/31/cloud-foundry-now-supports-play/) on Cloud Foundry blog. But on doing `vmc push --path=/path/to/dist.zip`, I am getting following warning:

```
Application Name: zentasks
[WARNING] Can't determine the Application Type.
Select Application Type:
```

I tried entering "play" as application type but it says `Unknown answer, please try again!`
I am running vmc 0.3.18 on Max OSX lion (10.7.4). JDK version is 1.6.0_33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If VMC is unable to guess the framework and asks you to specify which one it is, answer by entering the number next to the framework rather than the name itself.

However with the same version of VMC I was able to push this successfully to cloudfoundry.com and have it guess the framework correctly. I cloned the Play20 repository from github.com, moved to Play20/samples/scala/zentasks and issued the following commands;

```
$ play dist clean
$ vmc push --path==dist/zentask-1.0.zip
```

From there, vmc guessed the framework correctly and staged the application (http://dh-zentask.cloudfoundry.com/login) successfully, can you confirm you did the same?

**EDIT**

`vmc login` is required before `vmc push`

Comment: Yes I did the same. Where can I find the numbers against the frameworks? Is VMC supposed to list down the choices?

Comment: duh... I wasn't logged into cloudfoundry.com... it seems vmc first downloads the list of Application Types from server -- which requires login :)